# Send web socket message to server directly after connection

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, dart-html

The WebSocket server I use needs to receive a message after the connection.

The only way seems to use `WebSocket.connect` instead of  `WebSocketChannel.connect` (https://github.com/dart-lang/web_socket_channel/issues/209):

```dart
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

// ...

IOWebSocketChannel? _channel;

// ...

WebSocket.connect("ws://...").then((ws) {
  this._channel = IOWebSocketChannel(ws);
   _channel!.sink.add(msg);
}
```

But this is not supported by web. How is it possible to do that with both mobile and web support ?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
    WebSocket.connect(socketUrl).then((value) {
      _channel = IOWebSocketChannel(value);
      _channel?.stream.listen(onData,
          onError: onError, onDone: onDone, cancelOnError: true);
      debugPrint(
          "webSocket——readyState:${_channel?.innerWebSocket?.readyState}");
      if (_channel?.innerWebSocket?.readyState == 1) {
      } else {}
    }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).